# Is it possible to download Firebase Database node of which some subnodes are forbidden for current user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Let’s say there is node “Data” in realtime database that contains sub-nodes some of which current user can read and others that current user cannot read (due to security rules).

What happens when that user tries to read “Data” node? Will there be error or will it just return all sub-nodes of “Data” that current user can read?

(*try it yourselfs and similar answer will not be accepted, obviously I am seeking advice of more knowledgeble/experienced rather than trial-error approach*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That situation is not possible with Firebase Realtime Database.  The way security rules work is if a user has access to any node, they will have access to *all* nodes under that one.  You can't write a rule that cuts off access deeper in the tree.

Read the documentation (especially [authorization](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-authorization)) for more information.